# Compiled File as Folder Name, Fortran

Tags: fortran, output, directory, filenames, gfortran

Lets call our main code that takes requires a function `f(x)`, `Main.f90`, and source codes `S01.f90`, `S02.f90`, etc. that have varying forms of `f(x)`. I'd like to have `Main.f90` output the data it computes based on the `f(x)` from `Sxx.f90` to go into a folder "Sxx".

I compile through a bat file as `gfortran -o RunMe.exe Sxx.f90 Main.f90`.

At first it seems the code would need to be conscious of its' compiled components, but not only do I not know how to do this, I believe there's probably a much better way.

So far I have my code written to where I feed it a folder name from a `.txt`, but again, I'd like it to have it simply take what's already known from the source code.

If there are any other suggestions, please mention them! It doesn't have to be exactly as I stated. Here's the gist: Computation, Blueprint, Results. I want Computation in a father folder, and daughter folders, named after Blueprints, with results inside based on these Blueprints. The Blueprints can go in these daughter folders, or in their own. Whatever is simplest! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about [preprocessing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Preprocessing-and-conditional-compilation.html)? This would sound like the easiest way to do exactly what you want, although perhaps not the best. (I think the "best" way might be to have the module contained in `Sxx.f90` (you are using modules, aren't you) provide a `name` string. If each of your blueprints provides a `name`, then main can just use the relevant name. Going further you could use a derived type to provide a function and a name in one package).

Comment: I don't know about preprocessing. I am using modules. I thought about having the name in the external source, but was unsure of the best way to do that. Maybe as a simple function with string return... I'm not sure what you mean regarding the derived type.

Comment: I'd have a `character(len=*), parameter, public :: modName = "Sxx"` declaration in the first part of the module, so you could do something like `use Sxx, only : modName` in `Main.f90`.

Comment: Nifty, let me try that out and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @d_1999 It worked out pretty well. I slapped what you wrote in the external module, then simply took the path in my main ad concatenated it in :)

Answer (score 0):

How about simply generating several executables depending on which particular `Sxx.f90` was used for the build? For example,

```
gfortran -o RunMe01.exe S01.f90 Main.f90
gfortran -o RunMe02.exe S02.f90 Main.f90
```

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't necessarily do the sorting of outputs. Besides, my `main.f90` hardly takes time to compile so I don't mind the recompilation. It's tidier on my directories too.